# Where HTTP and SIP protocol existed In OSI Model?

Tags: http, network-programming, sip, osi

I am a beginner in network programming.  I am bit confused that in OSI Model where  HTTP and SIP protocol existed. Which layer are they in?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, every one I got it from another source and I realize that might question was not defining well. So, the answer i found is that SIP existed at all layers of OSI model.
 http://my.safaribooksonline.com/getfile?item=NzE1ZC9wL210L2M5Z2lzZTg5MDg3MWFzNHM0NXJhNzVfZWdwLy9ndHIwaWFzYzQxOV8uMTBqcHNo

Comment: No it doesn't. SIP is an application layer protocol. It runs over TCP and UDP which are transport layer protocols. They run over IP which is ... You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks I got some idea

Comment: But you never corrected or deleted your wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

They are both application-layer protocols.

As a matter of fact they don't exist in the OSI model at all. They are both TCP/IP protocols, and therefore fit into the application layer of the TCP/IP model.